# What does "acpi PNP0501:00: Still not present" mean?

Tags: linux-kernel, acpi

On my new laptop, I have an error in dmesg which occurs every 2 seconds:

```
acpi PNP0501:00: Still not present
```

What does this mean? How to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: The message means that the ACPI tables in the BIOS are buggy. A BIOS update may help.

`PNP0501` is the Plug&Play code for "16550A-compatible COM port". `:00` means the first device of this kind, as found in the ACPI DSDT table.

The error message `Still not present` means that the BIOS informed the OS that the status of the device changed, but when trying to configure it, the kernel noticed that it still isn't available.

In short

```
acpi PNP0501:00: Still not present
```

roughly translates to

"ACPI said there is a COM port on this mainboard, and it said that its status changed, so as it wasn't available before, it should be available by now, but it isn't."

It's a harmless warning, but further troubleshooting might be possible by using the [Linux ACPI debugging facility](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/acpi/debug.txt) and [DSDT overriding](https://01.org/linux-acpi/documentation/overriding-dsdt) or [method customizing](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/acpi/method-customizing.txt).